# Using Power Shell to Connect to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, powershell-2.0

I tried to add the Snapin (very basic step) and I am getting the following error.

Users>Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

---Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 2.
**At line:1 char:13
+ Add-PSSnapin <<<<  Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell:String) [Add-PS
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand**

Comment: Is SharePoint installed on the machine?

Comment: Yes. It is installed. Sharepoint 2010 in Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Did you try starting: SharePoint 2010 Management Shell? Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products -> SharePoint 2010 Management Shell

Comment: what's the result of `Get-PSSnapin -Registered`

Comment: All Done . I did not start the POWER SHELL AS ADMINISTRATOR. That was my mistake. Now everything is working fine.